# Issue with passing array to subprocess module while calling c program from python

Tags: python, c

I am using this code to call a C script from Python:

```
subprocess.check_output(["./s_cg",str(10),str(bb)])
```

The C script has code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int order;
int i,j;
order = atoi(argv[1]);

double* rhs = malloc(order * sizeof(double));
for (i = 0; i < order; i++) {
              scanf("%lf", &rhs[i])

          }


 for(i=0;i<order;i++)
  {
    printf("%lf",rhs[i]);
  }

    return 0;
```

}

The actual array bb passed is: `array([1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])`

But the printed array is:

> b'0.0000000.0000000.0000000.0000000.0000000.0000000.0000000.0000000.0000000.000000'

Comment: *The actual array passed is ...*. Where in above code is that array passed? and where is it printed? BTW: the `<` redirection is normally interpreted at shell level, not by the command, so I wander how the C program finds something to read...

Comment: bb is that array. The received array is printed through C program.

Comment: You should try to give enough code for others to reproduce, that is what is called a [mcve]. Without that I cannot guess what exactly you do, nor what you would want.

Comment: This itself is the full code. I have not written further C code yet. Right now, I am testing how to pass numpy arrayas or matrices to C from python.

Comment: What is the Python code that passes the array? `communicate` passes just nothing here!

Comment: The two lines mentioned above is the ony python code. Perhaps what you mentioned could be the problem. I am not familiar with the syntax. Can you please specify what to pass using communicate?

Comment: My question is just *where on earth can come `b'0.0000000.0000000.0000000.0000000.0000000.0000000.0000000.0000000.0000000.000000'`?* because nothing in shown code can print that. Is there at least a `print stdout` or anything else. If you do not want to answer, I will not be able to help...

Comment: Yes, this is print stdout

Answer (score 1):

The only channels between a process and its subprocess are pipes, that is simple streams of bytes.

The C programs receives an empty stdin stream through `communicate`, which is the same as reading from an empty file. It reads 10 values from that (and finds nothing) so every `scanf` returns -1 and does not change the original value of `rhs[i]` which just happens to be `0.`. Then it prints that on its stdout channel, that is 10 `0.` double value if `%f` format.

And the Python script receives that byte string in its `stdout` variable. The initial `b` is just the marker that `stdout` is a byte string and not an unicode string.

If that matters, there is no way to pass complex objects between a process and its subprocess: everything must be serialized at a string of bytes by the sender and deserialized by the receiver. The Python `struct` module is specifically good at serializing simple types in a portable way so that they can be easily deserialized in C.