# Calling C script from python not parsing inputs

Tags: python, c

I am running a c program from terminal as: `./cj 3 0.001 5 < matrix.txt`.

It prints the correct output as:

```
The code to be timed took 0.000011 seconds
Number of iterations: 3 
Solution to the matrix: 
2.000000
3.000000
1.000000
```

But calling the script from python as: `subprocess.check_output(["./cj",str(3),str(0.001),str(5),'<','matrix.txt'])`

generates output:

```
b'The code to be timed took 0.000001 seconds\nNumber of iterations: 0 \nSolution to the matrix: \n0.000000\n0.000000\n0.000000\n
```

Why so

Comment: The `<` operator is handled by the shell and not by the C program. So you'll either need to execute a shell, or you'll need to do what the shell would do (open the file and set `stdin=fileobj` in your `check_output` call).

Comment: Why not so? Meaning: what's the expected output? Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56168344/capture-result-of-bash-script-into-a-python-program/56168734#56168734 for a similar solution.

Comment: @DanielPryden: The other question doesn;t have an accepted answer. Although the redirection is poorly handled, I don't think it's the problem, as the program generated output, that *OP* simply doesn't know how to format.

Comment: Leaving all the redirection stuff aside: `subprocess.check_output(["./cj",str(3),str(0.001),str(5),'<','matrix.txt']).decode().split('\n')`?

Answer (score 0):

Input redirection using  `<`  is a shell feature. To use it, you need to run the subprocess with `shell=True`

```
subprocess.check_output("./cj" + str(3) + " " + str(0.001) + " " +str(5) + '<' + 'matrix.txt', shell=True)
```

This will spawn a new shell and run your command through that. However it's better to use a file-descriptor to provide input to the subprocess.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: I tried. It gives: b'Usage: ./cj [order] [tolerance] [iterations] [Optional suppress output(n)]\n'

Comment: You should pass the whole thing as a string and let the shell do the parsing of arguments. Edited my answer.

Comment: Don't use `shell=True` (which requires quoting difficulties and can introduce a security risk), you can just pass `stdin=open('matrix.txt')` and do the redirection without forking a whole process to do it for you.

Comment: @DanielPryden Thanks. It worked for file. Is it possible to pass numpy arrays as well using stdin? Something like stdin=array is not working?

Comment: @shaifaliGupta: No. An array is an object in memory. `stdin` is a pipe (stream of bytes). You could *serialize* the array to a stream of bytes, or there are other mechanisms. But your C code would need to be set up to read use the same mechanism. I suggest you ask a new question with the details of what you're actually trying to do, as there may be a better solution.

Comment: @DanielPryden Please have a look. The question is asked at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56157725/issue-with-passing-array-to-subprocess-module-while-calling-c-program-from-pytho